# Lebesgue measure has the Darboux property

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ be a measurable Lebesgue set, with $\lambda(A)>0$($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). Then, for every $b \in (0,\lambda(A))$, there exists a set $B$ measurable Lebesgue, $B\subset A$, with $\lambda(B)=b$. Can you give me a suggestion? I have no idea how to "build" the set $B$. It seems to me very likely to the Darboux property of functions..can it be used here?

Comment: Is $\lambda(A)$ assumed finite?

Comment: The problem only specifies that $\lambda(A)>0$.

Comment: For those interested in additional aspects about this property, see this [25 November 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4109674) archived at Math Forum. Also, google the phrase ["range of a measure"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22range+of+a+measure%22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is bounded. Thus, there is an interval $[a,c]$ such that $A\subseteq [a,c]$. Moreover, $\lambda(A)<\infty$. Let $f:[a,c]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(t)=\lambda([a,x]\cap A)$. Thus $f(x)<\infty$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

On the other hand, $f(a)=\lambda([a,a]\cap A)\le\lambda([a,a])=0$ and $f(c)=\lambda([a,c]\cap B)=\lambda(B)$.

Moreover, let $x,y\in[a,c]$. Set $u=\min\{x,y\}$, $v=\max\{x,y\}$. Therefore

$\begin{eqnarray}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=&|f(u)-f(v)|\\
&=&|\lambda([a,u]\cap A)-\lambda([a,v]\cap A)|\mbox{ and using $\lambda(A)<\infty$}\\
&=&\lambda([u,v]\cap A)\\
&\le&\lambda([u,v])\\
&=&v-u\\
&=&|x-y|.
\end{eqnarray}$

So $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[a,c]$. Then, there is $t\in(a,c)$ such that $f(t)=b$. Set $B=[a,t]\cap A$. The last means that $\lambda([a,t]\cap B)=b$.

This shows the case $A$ bounded. Can you do for $A$ unbounded?

**EDIT** If $A$ is unbounded, cover it by $[-n,n]$ and apply the last.

Comment: sinbadh, $f(b)$ shouldnt be $\lambda(A)$?

Comment: I will think about the other case.

Comment: I had a typing error. I corrected it.

Comment: I dont know if it is correct, but I will try an answer for $A$ unbounded.. if $A$ is unbounded, then it contains an interval of the shape $(a, \infty)$ or $[a, \infty)$ or the similary intervals with $- \infty$. suppose that $(a,\infty)\subset A$. Then, can I chose my set B to be the interval $(a,a+b)$, where $b> 0$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is unbounded but doesn't contain any interval like that.

Comment: But $\lambda(\mathbb{Z})=0$. Thus, we don't consider $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: That's true, but I was pointing out the error in user308560's argument. You can use $[0,1] \cup \mathbb{Z}$ instead.

Comment: My point is that there is no reason $A$ must contain an unbounded interval, just because $A$ is unbounded. You could also have $A = \cup_{n \geq 1} [n,n + 1/2^n]$

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 5):

I assume $A$ is defined to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $f(x) = \lambda(A \cap [-x,x])$. Then $f(x)$ is continuous, $f(0) = 0$, and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lambda(A)$, so by the intermediate value theorem, there is some value of $x$ for which $f(x) = b$.

Comment: Why is $f$ continous?

Comment: You need $f(A)<\infty$ for the first equality

Comment: @sinbadh I've edited the question to account for the possibility that $\lambda(A)$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes. It is rigth.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The Function $x \mapsto \lambda(A \cap (-\infty, x])$ is Lipschitz-continuous.